# How to replace text in a string column of a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, replace, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe like this:

```
range
"(2,30)"
"(50,290)"
"(400,1000)"
...
```

and I want to replace the `,` comma with `-` dash. I'm currently using this method but nothing is changed.

```
org_info_exc['range'].replace(',', '-', inplace=True)
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 484, accepted):

Use the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace):

```
df['range'] = df['range'].str.replace(',','-')

df
      range
0    (2-30)
1  (50-290)
```

**EDIT:** so if we look at what you tried and why it didn't work:

```
df['range'].replace(',','-',inplace=True)
```

from the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas.Series.replace) we see this description:

> str or regex: str: string exactly matching to_replace will be replaced
> with value

So because the str values do not match, no replacement occurs, compare with the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'range':['(2,30)',',']})
df['range'].replace(',','-', inplace=True)

df['range']

0    (2,30)
1         -
Name: range, dtype: object
```

here we get an exact match on the second row and the replacement occurs.

Comment: I wonder why the warning occurs: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Answer (score 125):

For anyone else arriving here from Google search on how to do a string replacement on *all* columns (for example, if one has multiple columns like the OP's 'range' column):
Pandas has a built in `replace` method available on a dataframe object.

`df.replace(',', '-', regex=True)`

Source: [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: `regex=True` was key for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

If you only need to replace characters in one specific column, somehow regex=True and in place=True all failed, I think this way will work:

```
data["column_name"] = data["column_name"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("characters_need_to_replace", "new_characters"))
```

lambda is more like a function that works like a for loop in this scenario.
x here represents every one of the entries in the current column.

The only thing you need to do is to change the "column_name", "characters_need_to_replace" and "new_characters".

Comment: This worked for my requirement. Thank you.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing to replace, but I get the "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame." warning.  The resulting dataframe is exactly what I want, but the warning is off-putting.  Rather than just turning the warning off, I'm in search of a non-warning-inducing way.

Comment: Thanks! Also you need to do some conversion in parameter of lambda function, like all x to string using `str(x)`

Answer (score 9):

Replace all commas with underscore in the column names

```
data.columns= data.columns.str.replace(' ','_',regex=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition, for those looking to replace more than one character in a column, you can do it using regular expressions:

```
import re
chars_to_remove = ['.', '-', '(', ')', '']
regular_expression = '[' + re.escape (''. join (chars_to_remove)) + ']'

df['string_col'].str.replace(regular_expression, '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Almost similar to the answer by Nancy K, this works for me:

```
data["column_name"] = data["column_name"].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace("characters_need_to_replace", "new_characters"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove two or more elements from a string, example the characters '$' and ',' :

```
Column_Name
===========
$100,000
$1,100,000
```

... then use:

```
data.Column_Name.str.replace("[$,]", "", regex=True)
```

=> `[ 100000, 1100000 ]`