# Pandas dataframe replace substring in column giving unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas

I'm really struggling with a simple string find and replace inside a Pandas dataframe column.

As a simple example, where I find " (C)" as part of a column value, I would want to replace this with "".

Here's some really simple code, which I can't get working using pd.str.replace(), which according to the first answer to this post ([Python Pandas: How to replace a characters in a column of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986489/python-pandas-how-to-replace-a-characters-in-a-column-of-a-dataframe)) I think should work (but guess that the space and brackets might be confusing things?). I've tried some regex's but must clearly be doing them wrong.

```
data = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'name': ['name1 (C)', 'name2 (B)', 'name3', 'name4']}
df_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df_data['name'] = df_data['name'].str.replace(' (C)', '')
print(df_data)
df_data['name'].replace({' (C)': ''}, inplace=True, regex=True)
print(df_data)
df_data['name'].replace({'( (C))': ''}, inplace=True, regex=True)
print(df_data)
```

Which yields the results:

```
   id       name
0   1  name1 (C)
1   2  name2 (B)
2   3      name3
3   4      name4
   id       name
0   1  name1 (C)
1   2  name2 (B)
2   3      name3
3   4      name4
   id       name
0   1  name1 (C)
1   2  name2 (B)
2   3      name3
3   4      name4
```

What is however really confusing is if I run this into just a plain string variable, everything works perfectly using the replace function.

```
mystr = "name (C)"
mystr.replace(" (C)", "")
Out[23]: 'name'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape `()` first, because special regex chars:

```
df_data['name'] = df_data['name'].str.replace(' \(C\)', '')
```

Or:

```
df_data['name'] = df_data['name'].replace(' \(C\)', '', regex=True)
```

---

```
print(df_data)
   id       name
0   1      name1
1   2  name2 (B)
2   3      name3
3   4      name4
```

Comment: Thanks very much - that works perfectly! Really appreciate it. I'm confused as to why it works with a regular string but not the .str.replace() method, because my understanding was that this essentially is a vectorised string in the first place, and would work in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Use escape for special characters while using [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
df_data['name'].str.replace(' \(C\)','')
```