# How to replace a character in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean some data that I have. I want to replace `)` with a blank space in specific rows which contain `)` in a `dataframe`.

Eg - `1948)`

I have identified those rows which have the extra string character `)`. I tried using `str.replace` but it didn't seem to work.

```py
movies['Year'].str[-1]==')'.replace(')','')
```

The code seems to run but doesn't clean the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas: How to replace a characters in a column of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986489/python-pandas-how-to-replace-a-characters-in-a-column-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: The right hand side of your statement, `')'.replace(')','')`, always gets converted to an empty string, `''`. You are also using a double equal sign, so this is a comparison, not an assignment. So this expression just tests whether the last character of each entry is an empty string (which it can never be), and returns the result as a series (all `False`s).

Comment: You could just use `movies['Year'] = movies['Year'].str.replace(')','')`.

Comment: Yeah. Realised that the == only compares and does not assign. Modified the code for it to run. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
movies = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'year':['1998)', '1999', '2000)', '2001)', '2002', '2003)']})
movies['year'] = movies['year'].apply(lambda s: s.replace(')', ''))
```

Will replace all instances of ')' even if not at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure why I was downvoted, perhaps it's not as efficient as other methods? It certainly works, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

If the `')'` only occur at the last, use [`pandas.Series.str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['1)', '2', '3)', '4', '5)'])
s.str.rstrip(')')
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: object
```