# Delete quotes in generated csv

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I need to delete the quotes from the csv.
I have a list of dictionaries of the following structure.

```
dicc= {"name":name, "number":number}
for i in api:
  list.append(dicc)

df=pd.DataFrame(list,columns= ['name', 'number'])
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'/name.csv', index = None, header=True,quoting= False)
```

The result is

```
name, number
A, 2
B, "1,2,3,4"
C, 3
```

The result I want:

```
name, number
A, 2
B, 1,2,3,4
C, 3
```

The format of the result is a comand "cat" of the csv. I need delete de quotes in the list.
I tried a replace and it didn't work.

Solution

```
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'/name.csv', index = None, header=True,sep="|")
```

Or separate the list of numbers by another character that is not ","

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas: How to replace a characters in a column of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986489/python-pandas-how-to-replace-a-characters-in-a-column-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: `df['number'] = df['number'].str.replace('"', '')`

Comment: I tried and not found...
Is not duplicated, the solution not found.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

export_csv = df.to_csv (r'/name.csv', index = None, header=True,sep="|")

Or separate the list of numbers by another character that is not ","