# Removes text between two tags python

Tags: python, dataframe, tags

I have dataframe. The df[0] contains

```
Eukariota|Organisme eukariotik (hewan, tumbuhan, fungi, dan protista) menyimpan kebanyakan DNA-nya dalam inti sel dan sebagian kecil sisanya dalam organel seperti mitokondria ataupun kloroplas. < ref > {{cite book|last = Russell|first = Peter|title = iGenetics|publisher = Benjamin Cummings|location = New York|year = 2001|isbn = 0-8053-4553-1 }} < /ref >
```

I want to remove:

```
< ref > {{cite book|last = Russell|first = Peter|title = iGenetics|publisher = Benjamin Cummings|location = New York|year = 2001|isbn = 0-8053-4553-1 }} < /ref >
```

How to do that? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace a characters in a column of a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986489/how-to-replace-a-characters-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example dataframe:

```
string1 = 'Eukariota|Organisme eukariotik (hewan, tumbuhan, fungi, dan protista) menyimpan kebanyakan DNA-nya dalam inti sel dan sebagian kecil sisanya dalam organel seperti mitokondria ataupun kloroplas. < ref > {{cite book|last = Russell|first = Peter|title = iGenetics|publisher = Benjamin Cummings|location = New York|year = 2001|isbn = 0-8053-4553-1 }} < /ref >'
string2 = 'Eukariota|Organisme eukariotik {{title}}'
data = [string1, string2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['text'])
```

Use pandas string replace and pass `regex = True`. If you have additional patterns you need to replace, use the `|` symbole to additionally add regex patterns.

```
new_df = df.text.replace('< ref >.*< \/ref > | {{.*}}','', regex = True)
print(new_df.values[0])
print(new_df.values[1])

Output:
Eukariota|Organisme eukariotik (hewan, tumbuhan, fungi, dan protista) menyimpan kebanyakan DNA-nya dalam inti sel dan sebagian kecil sisanya dalam organel seperti mitokondria ataupun kloroplas. < ref > < /ref >
Eukariota|Organisme eukariotik
```

Comment: How if I want to remove text between {{ and }}, I mean I want to remove this: {{text}}?

Comment: I added to my answer. Please accept as an answer it if solves this question. If you have a more focused question on regex, I suggest you ask another question. Thanks.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60038635/removes-text-between-2-tags-python] please answer

Comment: Sure, done. Small change but the whitespaces were the problems, refer to the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Regex.

This is the regex to use for the case you mention: `(\<\sref\s\>.*\<\s\/ref\s\>)`

```py
import re

string = 'Eukariota|Organisme eukariotik (hewan, tumbuhan, fungi, dan protista) menyimpan kebanyakan DNA-nya dalam inti sel dan sebagian kecil sisanya dalam organel seperti mitokondria ataupun kloroplas. < ref > {{cite book|last = Russell|first = Peter|title = iGenetics|publisher = Benjamin Cummings|location = New York|year = 2001|isbn = 0-8053-4553-1 }} < /ref >dasda'


string = re.sub('(\<\sref\s\>.*\<\s\/ref\s\>)', '', string)


print(string)

#output: Eukariota|Organisme eukariotik (hewan, tumbuhan, fungi, dan protista) menyimpan kebanyakan DNA-nya dalam inti sel dan sebagian kecil sisanya dalam organel seperti mitokondria ataupun kloroplas. dasda
```

Comment: How if the input is dataframe?

Comment: Convert each row to a string and save it back to a list that you can convert back to a dataframe? 

Im not that familiar with dataframes, but i guess regex could be used in a dataframe aswell?

Comment: I found this article about dataframes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` to match all text between the two tags. Using `< ref >.*< \/ref >` will match any text that sits within the two tags.

```
import re

string = 'Eukariota|Organisme eukariotik (hewan, tumbuhan, fungi, dan protista) menyimpan kebanyakan DNA-nya dalam inti sel dan sebagian kecil sisanya dalam organel seperti mitokondria ataupun kloroplas. < ref > {{cite book|last = Russell|first = Peter|title = iGenetics|publisher = Benjamin Cummings|location = New York|year = 2001|isbn = 0-8053-4553-1 }} < /ref >'

string = re.sub(f'< ref >.*< \/ref >', '', string)

string
'Eukariota|Organisme eukariotik (hewan, tumbuhan, fungi, dan protista) menyimpan kebanyakan DNA-nya dalam inti sel dan sebagian kecil sisanya dalam organel seperti mitokondria ataupun kloroplas. '
```

Answer (score 0):

with simple slicing?

```
new_string = string[0 : string.find("< ref >"]
```