# Removes text between 2 tags python

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, tags

I haved scraped data from Wikipedia and created a dataframe. `df[0]` contains

```
{{Infobox_President  |name = Mohammed Anwar Al Sadat  < br / >  محمد أنورالسادات  |nationality = Al Menofeia, Mesir  |image = Anwar Sadat cropped.jpg  |order = Presiden Mesir ke-3  |term_start = 20 Oktober 1970  |term_end = 6 Oktober 1981  |predecessor = Gamal Abdel Nasser  |successor = Hosni Mubarak  |birth_date =|birth_place = Mit Abu Al-Kum, Al-Minufiyah, Mesir  |death_place = Kairo, Mesir  |death_date =|spouse = Jehan Sadat  |party = Persatuan Arab Sosialis  < br / >  (hingga 1977)  < br / >  Partai Nasional Demokratik (Mesir)|Partai Nasional Demokratik  < br / >  (dari 1977)  |vicepresident =|constituency =}}  Jenderal Besar Mohammed Anwar Al Sadat () adalah seorang tentara dan politikus Mesir. Ia menjabat sebagai Presiden Mesir|Presiden ketiga Mesir pada periode 15 Oktober 1970 hingga terbunuhnya pada 6 Oktober 1981. Oleh dunia Barat ia dianggap sebagai orang yang sangat berpengaruh di Mesir dan di Timur Tengah dalam sejarah modern.
```

I want to remove:

```
{{Infobox_President  |name = Mohammed Anwar Al Sadat  < br / >  محمد أنورالسادات  |nationality = Al Menofeia, Mesir  |image = Anwar Sadat cropped.jpg  |order = Presiden Mesir ke-3  |term_start = 20 Oktober 1970  |term_end = 6 Oktober 1981  |predecessor = Gamal Abdel Nasser  |successor = Hosni Mubarak  |birth_date =|birth_place = Mit Abu Al-Kum, Al-Minufiyah, Mesir  |death_place = Kairo, Mesir  |death_date =|spouse = Jehan Sadat  |party = Persatuan Arab Sosialis  < br / >  (hingga 1977)  < br / >  Partai Nasional Demokratik (Mesir)|Partai Nasional Demokratik  < br / >  (dari 1977)  |vicepresident =|constituency =}}
```

How can I do this? I have tried

```
df['Body'] = df['Body'].replace('< ref >.< \/ref > | {{.}} | {{.*=}}','', regex = True)
df['Body'] = df['Body'].str.replace('\'\'\' | \n | [ | ] | \'\'','',regex=True)
```

but it doest work

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ohai post expected result

Answer (score 0):

This shall do the trick

```
import re
re.sub('^{{.*}}','', text)
```

you can `apply` this function to the column of your dataframe and it will transform the column.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, why it did not work was because of the extra spacing in your regex pattern, `| {{.*=}}` considers the space behind the curly spaces. As suggested as the other answer you can use the special operator `^` that anchors at the start of the line.

Else to apply a regex replace that matches that exact pattern then remove the whitespaces in your pattern:

```
text = '{{Infobox_President  |name = Mohammed Anwar Al Sadat  < br / >  محمد أنورالسادات  |nationality = Al Menofeia, Mesir  |image = Anwar Sadat cropped.jpg  |order = Presiden Mesir ke-3  |term_start = 20 Oktober 1970  |term_end = 6 Oktober 1981  |predecessor = Gamal Abdel Nasser  |successor = Hosni Mubarak  |birth_date =|birth_place = Mit Abu Al-Kum, Al-Minufiyah, Mesir  |death_place = Kairo, Mesir  |death_date =|spouse = Jehan Sadat  |party = Persatuan Arab Sosialis  < br / >  (hingga 1977)  < br / >  Partai Nasional Demokratik (Mesir)|Partai Nasional Demokratik  < br / >  (dari 1977)  |vicepresident =|constituency =}}  Jenderal Besar Mohammed Anwar Al Sadat () adalah seorang tentara dan politikus Mesir. Ia menjabat sebagai Presiden Mesir|Presiden ketiga Mesir pada periode 15 Oktober 1970 hingga terbunuhnya pada 6 Oktober 1981. Oleh dunia Barat ia dianggap sebagai orang yang sangat berpengaruh di Mesir dan di Timur Tengah dalam sejarah modern.'
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':[text]})

new_df = df.replace('< ref >.< \/ref >|{{.*}}','', regex = True)

new_df.text[0]

Output:
'  Jenderal Besar Mohammed Anwar Al Sadat () adalah seorang tentara dan politikus Mesir. Ia menjabat sebagai Presiden Mesir|Presiden ketiga Mesir pada periode 15 Oktober 1970 hingga terbunuhnya pada 6 Oktober 1981. Oleh dunia Barat ia dianggap sebagai orang yang sangat berpengaruh di Mesir dan di Timur Tengah dalam sejarah modern.'
```

Comment: Btw, I have text contains `< div class= " thumb tright "  style= " background-color: #f9f9f9; border:purple   1px solid #CCCCCC; margin:0.5em; " >  {| border= " 0 "  cellpadding= " 10 "  cellspacing= " 0 "  style= " font-size: 85%; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; margin: 0.3em; "  |valign= " top " |Berkas:EscherichiaColi NIAID.jpg|90px|Escherichia coli  |valign= " top " |Berkas:Tree Fern.jpg|90px|Tumbuhan paku  |-  |valign= " ------ " |Berkas:Goliath beetle.jpg|90px|Kumbang goliath  |valign= " ------ " |Berkas:` and I tried `df['Body'] = df['Body'].replace('<.*>','',regex=True)` but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? And again, if any of these answers have helped you please accept them, it is hard for other people to understand a question from a block of text