# Python- Cleaning the data from .txt file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

```html
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
import re


#LOAD THE DATA
df = pd.read_fwf('receipt.txt')

data= df.replace("£", "")

print(data)
```

I have attempted to clean this data and remove "£,:,-" could I please have help on how to best remove these symbols from my data? Please see image attached.

```html
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np


#LOAD THE DATA
df = pd.read_fwf('receipt.txt')
df.head()
```

[Screenshot of txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzjvl.png)

Comment: It would be much better if you posted the actual file, not a screenshot. Remember, if you make it more difficult for people to help you, you are less likely to get help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace a characters in a column of a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986489/how-to-replace-a-characters-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you for tip! I tried to attach .txt file though seems to be no place for file uploads, i referred to link you sent and received error- 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Answer (score 1):

You can use string replace and just substitute the undesired strings with empty string "", essentially deleting them.

Example:

```
str.replace("unwanted", "")
```

If you don't have to do this in every run of your code, consider data-cleaning outside of your script, with a simple shell " tr -d 'idontwantthis' "
(assuming Linux/OSX)

Comment: Thank you, i got the error -  replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Comment: I should have mentioned that "str" is your string variable. If you encounter any more errors, please paste your code

Comment: This is data in the txt file : £ 2800.02020-06-08 19:48:28.975953£ 500.02020-06-08 19:48:47.833899£ 800.02020-06-08 19:49:45.017243

Comment: i still get - 'empty data frame'

Comment: @Rimi Are you doing this operation do dataframe? Because you have to do it to a string variable. Load the file as a text and apply the fix, save it somewhere, THEN load new file as Dataframe again

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
readfilestr.replace("[the text to remove goes here]", "")
```

Comment: thank you I am getting the following-                                                                          Empty DataFrame
Columns: [£, 2800.02020-06-08, 19:48:28.975953£, 500.02020-06-08, 19:48:47.833899£, 800.02020-06-08, 19:49:45.017243]
Index: []

Comment: If you want to remove those symbols from every single item in the list, then you can do a for loop:   for i in len(mylist):            if mylist[i].__contains__("[unwanted]"):        mylist[i] = str(mylist[i]).replace(['unwanted'])   (also you can add a for loop if your is multi dimensional)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the  Regular Expressions (RegEx) module re.

```py
import re

string = "test with £,:,-"

new_string= re.sub('[£:-]', "", string)

print(new_string) # test with ,,
```

There are some good examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp),

Comment: you can read each row and clean the fields... i just showed an example of regex.