# Replacing characters in Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Would like to replace every character with another specific character in panda df['column'] or create a new column with new output.
Replace all K with B, 1 to 4, 2 to 3, 3 to 8.

Original column values:

```
0    K123D
1    K312E
2    K231G
```

Output:

```
0    B438D
1    B843E
2    B384G
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986489/how-to-replace-text-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Have you search about `str.replace()` & `.astype()` in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [str.translate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.translate.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["K123D",
                        "K312E",
                        "K231G"], columns=['data'])

table = str.maketrans({'K' : 'B', '1' : '4', '2' : '3', '3': '8'})

df['res'] = df['data'].str.translate(table)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    data    res
0  K123D  B438D
1  K312E  B843E
2  K231G  B384G
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `replace`

```
df.col = df.col.replace({'K':'B','1':'4','3':'8','2':'3'},regex=True)
0    B438D
1    B843E
2    B384G
Name: col, dtype: object
```