# Replace Method of python to remove the text from a particular column in python is not working

Tags: python, replace

I want to replace the "magneticfields\nD" in the Magnetic Declination column. I am generating this csv file from API. File look like this.

[CSV FILE GENERATE FROM API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWpjn.png)

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
from pathlib import Path

parameters = {
    "latd": 88, # [deg]
    "latm": 00, # [deg]
    "lats": 00, # [deg]
    "lond": 75, # [deg]
    "lonm": 00, # [deg]
    "lons": 00, # [deg]
    "elev" : 00, # [km]
    "year" : None, # [YYYY]
    "month" : '07', # [MM]
    "day": '01', # [DD]
    "Ein": 'D'  # [Model]
}

hostname = "https://api.geomagnetism.ga.gov.au/agrf"
df_1=pd.DataFrame()
for year in range(1985, 2025):
    try:
        parameters["year"] = year
        response = requests.get(hostname, params= dict(parameters, ps=str(year)))
        # extract JSON payload of response as Python dictionary
        json_payload = response.json()
        # raise an Exception if we encoutnered any HTTP error codes like 404
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        # handle any typo errors in url or endpoint, or just patchy internet connection
        print(e)
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        # handle HTTP error codes in the response
        print(e, json_payload['error'])
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        # general error handling
        print(e, json_payload['error'])
    else:
        json_payload = response.json()
        #print(json.dumps(json_payload, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        df = pd.DataFrame(json_payload)
        print(df)
        print(df.loc[['D'],['magneticFields']])
        new_row = {
            "SourceFile": hostname,
            "Year": year,
            "Magnetic Declination": df.loc[['D'],['magneticFields']],
            "Latitude": 88,
            "Longitude": 75
        }
        df_1 = df_1.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    df_1 = df_1[['Year', 'Latitude', 'Longitude','Magnetic Declination','SourceFile']]
    #df_1['Magnetic Declination'] = df_1['Magnetic Declination'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(r"magneticFields\nD ", ""))
    #df_1['Magnetic Declination'] = df_1['Magnetic Declination'].str.replace(r"..magneticFields\nD.....","",regex=True)
    #df_1['Magnetic Declination'] = df_1['Magnetic Declination'].str.replace('magneticFields\nD', '').astype(str)
    df_1["Magnetic Declination"] = df_1["Magnetic Declination"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" deg", ""))
    df_1.to_csv('magnetic_declination_australia_1.csv',index=False)
```

Tried all the methods but none of them is working.

```
df_1['Magnetic Declination'] = df_1['Magnetic Declination'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(r"magneticFields\nD ", ""))
df_1['Magnetic Declination'] = df_1['Magnetic Declination'].str.replace(r"..magneticFields\nD.....","",regex=True)
df_1['Magnetic Declination'] = df_1['Magnetic Declination'].str.replace('magneticFields\nD', '').astype(str)
```

Output should look this.

[FinalOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR6cV.png)

Can anyone help me how to fixed this? csv file that is generating from API attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XL3V8yYJZa_3zuXPitUaZV3k0tqErANi/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace text in a column of a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986489/how-to-replace-text-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @kshitiz It is not working. I check all stack overflow answers. Please read the full question.

Comment: Doesn't you just want to delete "magneticfields\nD" from Magnetic Declination column?

Comment: @kshitiz yes, I want to delete this from column. But the problem is that replace method is not working. For testing you need to run this code.

Comment: Have you checked spelling mistakes in replace method or some other common mistakes, because `print(df["Magnetic Declination"].str.replace("magneticFields\nD",""))` worked for me. Please check those mistakes and ask if it doesn't worked then also!

Comment: I have tried `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XL3V8yYJZa_3zuXPitUaZV3k0tqErANi/view?usp=sharing` for this file!

Comment: @kshitiz, just run the python code. It generate csv and then see weather it removed or not???

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in `df.loc[['D'],['magneticFields']]`. You are using `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` type as string. `df.loc[['D'],['magneticFields']]` returns the DataFrame and you are using this this directly without changing it.

`df.loc[['D'],['magneticFields']]` returns you

```
    magneticFields
D       69.650 deg
```

and now we can get `magneticFields` column and `D(First row)` from this DataFrame, like from other normal DataFrame by doing `df.loc[['D'],['magneticFields']]["magneticFields"][0]`.

Here's your final code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_payload)
print(df)
print(df.loc[['D'],['magneticFields']]["magneticFields"][0])
new_row = {
    "SourceFile": hostname,
    "Year": year,
    "Magnetic Declination": df.loc[['D'],['magneticFields']]["magneticFields"][0],
    "Latitude": 88,
    "Longitude": 75
}
df_1 = df_1.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

And you don't have to do any other fancy things with this like you have done haha.

Also don't forget to mark this as accepted, if it helps you.