# How to replace parentheses from a string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets say i have a dataframe like this:

```
       Col1
0     Test1_2345)
1     Test2_(123
2     Test3_567)_rt
3     Test5_874)
```

How can I replace "(" and ")" from the strings in Col1 and have a dataframe like this:

```
       Col1
0     Test1_2345
1     Test2_123
2     Test3_567_rt
3     Test5_874
```

I tried this one but it is not working:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].replace("(","",regex=True)
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].replace(")","",regex=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace text in a column of a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986489/how-to-replace-text-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: parenthesis are actual tokens in regex, you need to escape them if you literally mean a parenthesis.  `df.Col1.str.replace('\(|\)','')`  In this case, left OR right

Comment: Can also do a character class without escaping `df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].replace('[()]', '', regex=True)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris and henryecker, also this is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace everything other than `\w` . `\w` Matches alphanumeric characters and the underscore, _.

```
df1['Col1'] = df1['Col1'].str.replace('[^\w]','', regex=True)

0      Test1_2345
1       Test2_123
2    Test3_567_rt
3       Test5_874
```