# In a pandas string column, eliminate the text preceding a substring

Tags: python, pandas, substring

For example I have a Pandas DataFrame with a string column in which I would like to delete the `**bold**` text before a substring:

```
Column1
**Yon-RM-**CT 500M
**Abib-RM-**CT 500M
**Wal-RM-**CT 500M
**Sopxc-RM-**CT 1000M
```

Notice that the bold text could have different length but the substring ends in “-RM-“.

Comment: Welcome JOOC. What have you tried?

Comment: Please also provide an example of what you expect the result to look like, it's not clear from your description. What have you tried yourself, what problems did you run into? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is a pandas regex question. Please make sure to tag [tag:pandas]. Also, there are many duplicates, please search for them.

Comment: [**`df['Column1'].str.replace(pat, repl, ...)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986489/how-to-replace-text-in-a-string-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe) , see that duplicate question. The rest is just finding the specific regex for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all you want is CT 500M, and all follow the same format, apply a lambda function that splits by "-", and get the third index

```
 df["Column1"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["Column1"].split("-")[2], axis=1)
```

You could also split by "RM"

Comment: Don't use `apply` when you have the `str.split` vectorial method

Comment: I don't understand, why not?

Comment: This is much less efficient

Answer (score 0):

Use the `re.sub()` method from the `re` module to replace the string you don't want with ''. Apply it to the column. Something like this should work.

```
for i in Column1:
   i = re.sub('^\*.*\*', '', i)
```

or

```
Column1 = [re.sub('^\*.*\*', '', i) for i in Column1]
```

`^\*.*\*` basically finds all characters between a starting * and the last *. Re.sub() finds each one and substitutes it with whatever you choose.

[Here's the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove everything between double asterisks, use `Series.str.replace` with a regex (`'\*\*.*?\*\*'`):

```
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].str.replace('\*\*.*?\*\*', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
    Column1
0   CT 500M
1   CT 500M
2   CT 500M
3  CT 1000M
```